# git - how to store local development changes

Tags: git, branch

I have a master branch with an application in production configuration (not managed by me) and I would love to have local development environment with some minor changes (URLs to local testing resources, dependencies not used in production etc.).

Keeping changes uncommited is not a solution for me - it is not simple to manage it.

I need to be able to regularly merge (or to get somehow) new changes from master to my local branch and at the end to push local changes (without the configuration of course) back to master.

What is the best approach to do that?

Comment: you could have a `.env` file or `config` that stores the production/local variables depending on your environment. You wouldn't store this in the repository for security purposes.

The next thing you'd probably want is to have a `develop` and `production` branch - where `production` has `releases` like `production/release-some-date`

Comment: I know the design is not perfect, I'm new to this project and I looked for a quick solution (until done properly) with some "git branching magic"

Comment: the issue is - that you'll have to commit changes to the master branch with the evn variables regardless (to ensure they are committed to version control as well as syncing/merging branches)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a very flexible solution, but a temporary one until you've got a proper solution.
Create a new "devsettings" branch, set up your local dev environment urls etc. and commit.
Whenever you have done work in master and want to test it in a dev environment, cherry-pick the devsettings commit, do your tests and reset before merging.

So for testing your flow would be something like

```
git cherry-pick <devsettings-commit-hash>
# do your tests
git reset HEAD~1
```